# machine learning: best technique to deal with a lot of categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data

Suppose I have a 5000-rows matrix with 10 columns and most of them are filled with categorical data (strings) and in each column I have 10-30 different strings. What is the best ideal way/algorithm to deal with it in python? OneHotEncoder would give me a very large matrix

Comment: Use OneHotEncoding and then fit some model and get 'feature_importance'. Use Top 10-15% features for training then again check accuracy and f-score. This will reduce no. features. Also, accuracy and f-score will be reduced slightly. Works for supervised learning.

Comment: You can try using Gradient Boosting with categorical features support. Check out CatBoost https://catboost.yandex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scikit-learn's one-hot encoder uses sparse matrices by default, so exact matrix shape is not problematic (because it won't store nonzero entries).

Some simple sklearn algorithms (linear models, trees, Naive Bayes) are able to handle such sparse data - for concrete example see [Computational Performance](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computational_performance.html#influence-of-the-input-data-representation) section or [Classification of text documents using sparse features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is ideal but you could use scipy. You could try one-hot encoding alongside with [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) representation for the resulting matrix.

Answer (score -2):

Why Not use graph database such:https://neo4j.com
but my recommendation is JCR : [modeshape.jboss.org](http://modeshape.jboss.org)
you can make deeper leaf indexing and get  very flexible query

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't know them, now I read about it and try